# facebook PHP SDK cannot work in different PHP versions

Tags: php, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a sample code to test if my website can receive data from facebook.I ran this code locally on a webmatrix server running PHP 5.4 with no problems.I also ran that code on a machine running WAMP server with PHP 5.5 again without any problems.But when I ran it on a VM with ubuntu 12.04 and PHP 5.5.26 (according to phpinfo() function)or in a coding.io VM with PHP 5.9 it shows no output.Of course I have checked everywhere to keep the same path with the facebook sdk folder and that is ok.Any help would be appreciated on this strange problem.

Here is my test code:

```
<?php
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once( '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;


$facebook = FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxxxxxxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
FacebookSession::enableAppSecretProof(false);
$session = new FacebookSession('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

//from user
$myurl = (isset($_POST['url']) ? $_POST['url'] : null); //not of any use here now
$objRequest = '/461598630586060';


try {
  $response = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET',$objRequest))->execute();
  $response='success';

  } catch (FacebookRequestException $ex) {

  $response='fail';
} catch (\Exception $ex) {

  $response='fail';
}

echo $response;
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure about the php version? There is no 5.9 version

Comment: It's probably not caused by the PHP version but rather some sort of server / PHP configuration. You get no output at all? What if you insert some `echo 'now my script is here';` lines between your code, so you could figure out which parts are executed, how far the script runs and when it breaks? Don't you have an error log somewhere (can't remember off the top of my head where PHP errors are logged by default, though, `phpinfo()` should tell you).

Comment: Ooops,php version 5.5.9!I tried adding some echos but as fas as I can figure out,nothing is executed after first "require_once".But it is just that there is no output and i do not have a clue why is that happening.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by just replacing all `require_once` statements with `require __DIR__ . '/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php';` and now everything works like a charm!